# SCDF yarn connection error

Tags: hadoop-yarn, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have deployed spring cloud dataflow on a virtual yarn cluster. starting the server `./bin/dataflow-server-yarn` executes correctly. and returns

```
2016-11-02 10:31:59.786  INFO 42493 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2016-11-02 10:31:59.787  INFO 42493 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn:9393.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2016-11-02 10:31:59.787  INFO 42493 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2016-11-02 10:31:59.896  INFO 42493 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9393 (http)
2016-11-02 10:31:59.901  INFO 42493 --- [           main] o.s.c.d.server.yarn.YarnDataFlowServer   : Started YarnDataFlowServer in 16.026 seconds (JVM running for 16.485)
```

I can then start `./bin/dataflow-shell` , from here i can import apps create and list streams without errors; however, if i try to deploy the created stream the following connection error happens

```
2016-11-02 10:52:58.275  INFO 42788 --- [nio-9393-exec-8] o.s.c.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnAppDeployer  : Deploy request for org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.core.AppDeploymentRequest@23d59aea
2016-11-02 10:52:58.275  INFO 42788 --- [nio-9393-exec-8] o.s.c.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnAppDeployer  : Deploying request for definition [AppDefinition@3350878c name = 'time', properties = map['spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.requiredGroups' -> 'ticktock', 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination' -> 'ticktock.time']]
2016-11-02 10:52:58.275  INFO 42788 --- [nio-9393-exec-8] o.s.c.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnAppDeployer  : Parameters for definition {spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.requiredGroups=ticktock, spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=ticktock.time}
2016-11-02 10:52:58.275  INFO 42788 --- [nio-9393-exec-8] o.s.c.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnAppDeployer  : Deployment properties for request {spring.cloud.deployer.group=ticktock}
2016-11-02 10:52:58.276  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@6d68eeb7
2016-11-02 10:52:58.276  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : started RESOLVEINSTANCE WAITINSTANCE STARTCLUSTER CREATECLUSTER PUSHARTIFACT STARTINSTANCE CHECKINSTANCE PUSHAPP CHECKAPP WAITCHOICE STARTINSTANCECHOICE PUSHAPPCHOICE  /  / uuid=d7e5224f-c5f0-47c9-b2c2-066b117cc786 / id=null
2016-11-02 10:52:58.276  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@79158163
2016-11-02 10:52:58.280  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMnull found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@79158163
2016-11-02 10:52:59.281  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:00.282  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:01.283  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:02.283  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:03.284  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:04.285  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:05.286  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:06.287  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:07.288  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:08.289  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:08.290  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.c.d.s.y.DefaultYarnCloudAppService   : Cachekey STREAMapp--spring.yarn.appName=scdstream:app:ticktock,--spring.yarn.client.launchcontext.arguments.--spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.appmaster.artifact=/dataflow//artifacts/cache/ found YarnCloudAppServiceApplication org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.yarn.YarnCloudAppServiceApplication@7d3bc3f0
2016-11-02 10:53:09.294  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:10.295  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:11.296  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:12.297  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:13.297  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:14.298  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:15.299  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:16.300  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:17.301  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:18.302  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: localhost/192.168.137.135:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2016-11-02 10:53:18.361  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] org.apache.hadoop.fs.TrashPolicyDefault  : Namenode trash configuration: Deletion interval = 0 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
2016-11-02 10:53:18.747  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped org.springframework.statemachine.support.DefaultStateMachineExecutor@6d68eeb7
2016-11-02 10:53:18.747  INFO 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.s.support.LifecycleObjectSupport     : stopped RESOLVEINSTANCE WAITINSTANCE STARTCLUSTER CREATECLUSTER PUSHARTIFACT STARTINSTANCE CHECKINSTANCE PUSHAPP CHECKAPP WAITCHOICE STARTINSTANCECHOICE PUSHAPPCHOICE  /  / uuid=d7e5224f-c5f0-47c9-b2c2-066b117cc786 / id=null
2016-11-02 10:53:18.747 ERROR 42788 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.c.d.s.y.AbstractDeployerStateMachine : Passing through error state DefaultStateContext [stage=STATE_ENTRY, message=GenericMessage [payload=DEPLOY, headers={artifact=org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:time-source-kafka:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, appVersion=app, groupId=ticktock, definitionParameters={spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.requiredGroups=ticktock, spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=ticktock.time}, count=1, clusterId=ticktock:time, id=f0f7b54e-e59d-69c0-a405-f0907fa46343, contextRunArgs=[--spring.yarn.appName=scdstream:app:ticktock, --spring.yarn.client.launchcontext.arguments.--spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.appmaster.artifact=/dataflow//artifacts/cache/], artifactDir=/dataflow//artifacts/cache/, timestamp=1478083978275}], messageHeaders={artifact=org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:time-source-kafka:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, appVersion=app, groupId=ticktock, definitionParameters={spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.requiredGroups=ticktock, spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=ticktock.time}, count=1, clusterId=ticktock:time, id=f0f7b54e-e59d-69c0-a405-f0907fa46343, contextRunArgs=[--spring.yarn.appName=scdstream:app:ticktock, --spring.yarn.client.launchcontext.arguments.--spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.appmaster.artifact=/dataflow//artifacts/cache/], artifactDir=/dataflow//artifacts/cache/, timestamp=1478083978275}, extendedState=DefaultExtendedState [variables={artifact=org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:time-source-kafka:jar:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, appVersion=app, appname=scdstream:app:ticktock, definitionParameters={spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.requiredGroups=ticktock, spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=ticktock.time}, count=1, messageId=f0f7b54e-e59d-69c0-a405-f0907fa46343, clusterId=ticktock:time, error=org.springframework.yarn.YarnSystemException: Call From master/127.0.1.1 to localhost:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/127.0.1.1 to localhost:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused}], transition=org.springframework.statemachine.transition.DefaultExternalTransition@77c2bbfc, stateMachine=UNDEPLOYMODULE DESTROYCLUSTER STOPCLUSTER DEPLOYMODULE RESOLVEINSTANCE WAITINSTANCE STARTCLUSTER CREATECLUSTER PUSHARTIFACT STARTINSTANCE CHECKINSTANCE PUSHAPP CHECKAPP WAITCHOICE STARTINSTANCECHOICE PUSHAPPCHOICE ERROR READY ERROR_JUNCTION UNDEPLOYEXIT DEPLOYEXIT  / ERROR / uuid=436b73fe-991a-4c22-a418-334f895d41e5 / id=null, source=null, target=null, sources=null, targets=null, exception=null]
2016-11-02 10:53:18.748  WARN 42788 --- [nio-9393-exec-8] o.s.c.d.s.c.StreamDeploymentController   : Exception when deploying the app StreamAppDefinition [streamName=ticktock, name=time, registeredAppName=time, properties={spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.requiredGroups=ticktock, spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=ticktock.time}]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.yarn.YarnSystemException: Call From master/127.0.1.1 to localhost:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/127.0.1.1 to localhost:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

changing the IP address to the localhost,yielded same results.
here is my server.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    org.apache.hadoop: INFO
    org.springframework.yarn: INFO
maven:
  remoteRepositories:
    springRepo:
      url: https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot
spring:
  main:
    show_banner: false
  # Configured for Hadoop single-node running on localhost. Replace with property values reflecting     your
  # actual Hadoop cluster when running in a distributed environment.
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://192.168.137.135:8020
    resourceManagerHost: 192.168.137.135
    resourceManagerPort: 8032
    resourceManagerSchedulerAddress: 192.168.137.135:8030
  # Configured for Redis running on localhost. Replace at least host property when running in a
  # distributed environment.
  redis:
    port: 6379
    host: 192.168.137.135
  # Configured for an embedded in-memory H2 database. Replace the datasource configuration with     properties
  # matching your preferred database to be used instead, if needed, or when running in a distributed     environment.
  #rabbitmq:
  # addresses: localhost:5672
  # for default embedded database
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:19092/mem:dataflow
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
#  # for mysql/mariadb datasource
#  datasource:
#    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB
#    username: yourUsername
#    password: yourPassword
#    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
#  # for postgresql datasource
#  datasource:
#    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/yourDB
#    username: yourUsername
#    password: yourPassword
#    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9093
          zkNodes: localhost:2181
    config:
      enabled: false
      server:
        bootstrap: true
    deployer:
      yarn:
        app:
          baseDir: /dataflow
          streamappmaster:
            memory: 512m
            virtualCores: 1
            javaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
          streamcontainer:
            priority: 5
            memory: 256m
            virtualCores: 1
            javaOpts: "-Xms64m -Xmx256m"
          taskappmaster:
            memory: 512m
            virtualCores: 1
            javaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
          taskcontainer:
            priority: 10
            memory: 256m
            virtualCores: 1
            javaOpts: "-Xms64m -Xmx256m"
#  yarn:
#    hostdiscovery:
#      pointToPoint: false
#      loopback: false
#      preferInterface: ['eth', 'en']
#      matchIpv4: 192.168.0.0/24
#      matchInterface: eth\\d*
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, it seems the port was the problem. I changed the port number on the yarn-site.xml and did the same on the servers.xml and voila!!